# How do I calculate $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(2^{3x+1}\right)^{1/x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

So I have a function that looks like this.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(2^{3x+1}\right)^{1/x}$$

Note the original form was the n-root of the inner power function

My task is to find out if the limit converges or diverges, and at what value if it converges. My question is what is the cleanest way to do this? L'Hopitals seems to be too messy since I have to do a derivative more than once of a double power function and I'm not sure how I would apply the Squeeze Theorem or the 'divide-by-largest-polynomial' technique.

This is an even numbered review problem so the answer is not given. This isn't really homework since it's optional so a written out technique would be very helpful.

Comment: limit to what x

Comment: Is the function $\left( 2^{3x+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ ?  And  do you want the limit for $x \to \infty$ ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. This is my first time using MathJax in a question and I missed that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases it helps to simplify the expression. In this case, you can jump to the conclusion almost immediately by the [laws of indices](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=laws%20of%20indices&oq=laws%20of%20ind&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3391j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). To be specific, you need the multiplication and power rules:

$$(2^{3x+1})^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
$$=({2^{3x}}^{\frac{1}{x}}) * ({2^{1}}^{\frac{1}{x}})$$
$$=(2^{(3x)(\frac{1}{x})}) * 2^{1/x}$$
$$=2^3 * 2^{1/x}$$

What happens to the value of $2^{1/x}$ as $x$ tends to infinity? How does this change the result of the expression, if it does?

Comment: This is a more complete and thorough version of @Emilio Novati 's post. Feel free to check it out.

Comment: Yeah, this was exactly what I was looking for. Brilliant, thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the minor mistake - the plus signs in the previous edit were actually supposed to be multiplication signs. Thanks for giving me the accept!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

write the function as $ f(x)=2^{\frac{3x+1}{x}}=2^3 \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{x}}$